# VB.Net Windows Application requires rebuild every time even for small changes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created windows application in VB.Net 2010. The problem is that even for a small change, I have to rebuild the project. Without rebuilding it, the changes do not take place. What may be the problem or something else?

Comment: Seeing your comment to Joel, it appears you're experiencing some difference where Build doesn't work but Rebuild does. Is this affecting *all* projects or just one? (If it's all projects, can you list the steps you go through from creating a new project to having the issue manifest itself?)

Comment: The problem is not for all other projects. Only for this.

Comment: Okay, you need to apply some basic problem solving techniques, if you want help. If you create a new project, copy everything over from the current project, and try to use that, does it exhibit the same problem? If not, use the new project, abandon the old, and move on with your life. If so, start applying binary chops to identify the aspects of your project that are causing the issue versus those that aren't. At the moment, this is "guess why my code doesn't work" when we can't even see your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem here. That's the way it's supposed to work. Unlike vbscript and vba, which were interpretted, VB.Net is a compiled language.

Comment: But even build only, does not work. is it necessary to rebuild only each time for a small change?